# Set a label in a cell that is controlled by a stepper - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hi I have a UITableView and I am dymanically inserting cells into it that contain a UIStepper and a UILabel. The UILabel shows the value of the UIStepper.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    [cell.textLabel setText:[self.myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc]init];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", stepper.value];

    [cell addSubview:stepper];
    [cell addSubview:label];

    [stepper addTarget:self action:@selector(incrementStepper:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return cell;
}
```

I have removed some of the above lines that do the formatting for clarities sake but this works and everything is ok.

```
-(void)incrementSkillStepper:(id)sender
{
    UIStepper *stepper = (UIStepper*)sender;
    //set the label that is in the same cell as the stepper with index stepper.value.
}
```

When I click the stepper in the specific cell I want the label in the same cell to increment, but my problem is in which the way that addtarget works - I can only send the sender which in this case is the stepper to the event which means it doesnt have access to the dynamically created label. Does anybody know how I can set the text of the label from the incrementStepper delegate method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `[sender superview]` to get the cell that it's in,

```
-(void)incrementSkillStepper:(id)sender
{
    UIStepper *stepper = (UIStepper*)sender;
    UITableViewCell* cell =  [stepper superview];

    UIView* subview = [[cell subviews] lastObject]; // Make sure your label *is* the last object you added.

    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

you can also loop thru the `[cell.contentView subviews]` `array`, and get the label you need, better give the label a `tag` value, and use `viewWithTag`

Comment: Ok I have tried that and it didnt work. I've tried putting the lines NSLog(@"%@", [cell.contentView subviews]);
    NSLog(@"%d", [[cell.contentView subviews]count]); at the end of the method and the array only contains cell.textlabel and the count is 1. I am not sure why that would be the case as it seems like this should work.

Comment: try and use  [cell.contentView addSubview:stepper]; and [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

Comment: Cool that worked however I had to change the subview instatiation line to UIView* subview = [[cell subviews] lastObject];. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set tag to UIStepper as indexPath.row and set tag to label as indexPath.row+999.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc]init];
    stepper.tag = indexPath.row;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    label.tag = indexPAth.row + 999;

    //......
}
```

Now in delegate method of UIStepper, you can find label in that cell like this

```
-(void)incrementSkillStepper:(id)sender
{
    UIStepper *stepper = (UIStepper*)sender;
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender.tag + 999];
    //now this is same label as you want. Now you can change the value of label as you want

}
```

Comment: what if there are more than one sections.?

Comment: then you can set tag like this:
[label setTag:((indexPath.section & 0xFFFF) << 16) |
     (indexPath.row & 0xFFFF)];

Comment: And in delegate method you can fetch row and section like this:
 NSUInteger section = ((sender.tag >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
    NSUInteger row     = (sender.tag & 0xFFFF);

Answer (score 0):

You should update the model with the value of the stepper, and then set the label's value based on that value in the model. You should give the stepper a tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath that's equal to the indexPath.row, and in the stepper's action method, set the value of a property in your model to the stepper's value. Then, reload the row at that same indexPath.

```
(void)incrementSkillStepper:(UIStepper *)sender {
    NSInteger row = sender.tag;
    [self.theData[row] setObject:@(sender.value) forKey:@"stepperValue"];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: @[row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, you would have something like this to populate the label:

```
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.theData[indexPath.row][@"stepperValue"]];
```

In this example, I'm assuming you have an array of dictionaries (theData) that has all the data you need to populate the cells. One of the dictionary keys, "stepperValue" would be used to store the stepper value as an NSNumber.