# UITable view not displaying button in cell iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, customization

i have implemented this code, its showing both labels, but button not coming in cell tell me the issue

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageOnRightCell";

     UILabel *mainLabel, *secondLabel;
     UIButton *buttonMe;

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

        mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 220.0, 15.0)];
        mainLabel.tag = MAINLABEL_TAG;
        mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        mainLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

        secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 220.0, 25.0)];
        secondLabel.tag = SECONDLABEL_TAG;
        secondLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        secondLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        secondLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        secondLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];

        buttonMe = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260.0, 7.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
        buttonMe.tag = PHOTO_TAG;
        buttonMe.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:buttonMe];
   }
   else {
       mainLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:MAINLABEL_TAG];
       secondLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:SECONDLABEL_TAG];
       buttonMe = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:PHOTO_TAG];
   }

   mainLabel.text = @"main text";
   secondLabel.text = @"Secon text";
   buttonMe.titleLabel.text=@"oh";

   return cell;
}
```

please help for this

Comment: What is the size for your cell? As you are adding button with X: 260 can you check if it is going outside rect of cell?

Comment: i also try axter settin x=200 or other values its not wrking

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633824/how-to-add-uibutton-to-uitableviewcell-dynamically

Open the Above link...May be it will use full for u kritika...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with

```
    buttonMe = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260.0, 7.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
```

it will give you back a UIButton of type `UIButtonTypeCustom` which will by default be transparent/Clear color.

so may be it is getting added on the cell but is not visible, try and change the background color of the button and check if its still not visible.

Comment: its coming now, i have 4 section and multiple rows in section, i m adding button to each row and it should act as separate, how i assign the tag values

Comment: you should ask it as a new question.. but anyways one solution to set tag like this: [button setTag:((indexPath.section & 0xFFFF) << 16) | (indexPath.row & 0xFFFF)];
\n
And in delegate method you can fetch row and section like this: NSUInteger section = ((sender.tag >> 16) & 0xFFFF); NSUInteger row = (sender.tag & 0xFFFF);

Comment: also if you need the cell you can use `UITableViewCell* cell =  [button superview];` refer to my other answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16684923/1069115)

Comment: will u please explane it to me..((indexPath.section & 0xFFFF) << 16) | (indexPath.row & 0xFFFF)] please for my concept

Comment: what did you not understand ?? , also you should accept an answer that solved your previous problem, before asking a new one.

Comment: thias condition what is it "& 0xFFFF) << 16"

Comment: have a look at [Objective-C 2.0 Operators](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions) it'l help you understand Shift Operators

Answer (score 0):

To create button programatically use this code

```
  UIButton *buttonMe = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [buttonMe addTarget:self
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [buttonMe setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonMe.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    buttonMe.tag = PHOTO_TAG;

    buttonMe.frame = CGRectMake(260.0, 7.0, 30.0, 30.0);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:buttonMe];
```

Note  i included the code for setting the action also.When you click it will try the method `aMethod:` ,so define it also ,otherwise will appear a crash on button click event

Comment: [cell.contentView addSubview:buttonMe], shoul i not use this

Comment: Edited to your requirement .Use this

Comment: I have modified the code.Try it and lemme know it works or not

Comment: still its not coming, may be some other problem

Comment: all labels are visible?If yes trythe code along with the frame of a label.Try with out autoresizing code

Comment: @KritikaBansal : The code is shown here is perfect . Check with your cell Frame .And try with different CGRectMake Values ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, set backgroundColor for buttonMe:buttonMe.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
and change "buttonMe.titleLabel.text=@"oh"" to "[buttonMe setTitle:@"oh" forState:UIControlStateNormal];"